# how does javafx main method launch(args) work?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

The methods outside the main method are not mentioned in main method.
The main method only contain `launch(args);`

I thought it need to call the methods outside the method that make it work in the program?

So how does `launch(args)` work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you open a template of JavaFX in Netbeans it have a JavaDoc explaining it:

```
/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

So essentially, **it shouldn't even be called** as it is JavaFX, however if it is called then it will just pass the command line arguments (args) to the javafx.application.Application.launch which will open the JavaFX as expected.

In case you are still wondering how does the launch works, then you probably should check its [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/application/Application.java).

Comment: thanks bro. you are champion. I should check the source code.

Comment: On most modern JVMs/IDEs the answer is no. Again, the purpose of `public static void main(String[] args){}` there is a fallback mechanism for IDEs with limited JavaFX support. _(aka older ones)_

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is still required when having native launchers using Javapackager or javafx-maven-plugin. Don't know why the documentation says "main" isn't required.